# Install Wizard restart

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wizard

So, I'm trying to make an install wizard for my program.
However, if you type in "n", It will ask if you are sure if you want to cancel, But then when you press "n" I want it to go back to the top. Is this possible?

```
echo "Would you like to start the NJDTL Install Wizard? [y/n]"
read startYN
if [ $startYN == y ]
  then
      echo "Starting Install Wizard. . ."
      mkdir ~/.NJDTL
    fi
    if [ $startYN == n ]
      then
          echo "Are you sure you want to cancel the Install Wizard? [y/n]"
          read CancelConfirm
          if [ $CancelConfirm = y ]
            then
                echo "Cancelling Install. . ."
                exit
              fi
          if [ $CancelConfirm = n ]
            then
                echo "Chose "n". Continuing Installation. . ."
        fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart your script:

```
exec $0
```

Update - to preserve the command line you can use:

```
exec $0 "$@"
```